# Why does an if block work but a && statement doesn't work for executing a try catch block?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Basically wanted the issue && block to work the same as if(issue) block in my nextjs component for an edit form which basically detects if there is a prop passed named issues passed on to the component. If it does exist then the issue && statement would be executed. However it isn't working and chatgpt recommends that I use the if block instead. The error that it shows is -

```
Parsing error: ':' expected.eslint
(property) try: {
    setIsSubmitting(: any): any;
    await: Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>;
    router: AppRouterInstance;
    "": any;
}
```

```
issue && {
      try {
        setIsSubmitting(true);
        await axios.post("/api/issues", data);
        router.push("/issues");
      } catch (error) {
        setIsSubmitting(false);
        setError("An unexpected error occurred");
      }
    }
    
if (issue) {
    try {
        setIsSubmitting(true);
        await axios.post("/api/issues", data);
        router.push("/issues");
      } catch (error) {
        setIsSubmitting(false);
        setError("An unexpected error occurred");
      }
}
```

Comment: Because JavaScript syntax does not allow it. A `try` - `catch` block is a *statement*, and you can't put a statement in the middle of an expression.

Comment: Why don't you just use the proper `if` block?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the syntax for `&&` expects its operands to be expressions (at a high-level, code which evaluates to a value, such as `1+1` evaluating to the value of `2`):

```
<expression> && <expression>
```

Since an expression is expected the opening `{` would be interpreted as the start of an object literal (a valid expression) rather than a code block (which is a statement, not an expression). However, since a try-catch statement is invalid within an object literal you get an error. You could force something like this by putting a function-expression in as the second operand and then immediately invoking it:

```js
issue && (() => {
  try {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    await axios.post("/api/issues", data);
    router.push("/issues");
  } catch (error) {
    setIsSubmitting(false);
    setError("An unexpected error occurred");
  }
})();
```

But this is quite unreadable, so instead, I'd highly suggest avoiding this and using the `if` statement approach.